# Problem Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem, when i try to insert a database to the PHPMyAdmin i'm facing with this error

I tried to delete the `DEFINER=`root`@`localhost with no results.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`feneris`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `customordersemails`  AS  select `customorders`.`email` AS `email` from `customorders` where `customorders`.`email` <> '' ;
```

Comment: is the error creating the view or querying from the view? What user creates the view? What permissions does `feneris@localhost` user have on `customorders`? This question should be on https://dba.stackexchange.com as SO is a coding site.

Comment: *I tried to delete the DEFINER* should solve that problem. Please show that modified code and verify that "with no results" means "I also get that same error" (and not something else you didnt expect but isn't that error, e.g. it didnt create that view, or the view is not working).